# 'Not a statement', '; expected'

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting both these errors (on the marked line) with the following code in java;

```
    String data[] = file.getInput();

    while(data[0] != "X"){
        String ID = data[0];
        String firstName = data[1];
        String lastName = data[2];

        data[] = file.getInput(); //errors occurr here  
    }
```

Note that file.getInput() is a method that returns an array of Strings from a CSV file using the InputReader.

Comment: Just use `data = file.getInput();`

Comment: That causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on the line:
String firstName = data[1];

Comment: remove the `[]` from `data[] = ...`

Comment: then there are no result in `file.getInput();` :)

Comment: Ok, I think I know what the problem is. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is fixed, but you probably want to replace the `!= "X"` by some `!"X".equals(`

Comment: Aside from anything else, `data[0] != "X"` is incorrect. Details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Many thanks guys. that .equals thing gets me every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ‘[]’ from data :

```
data = file.getInput();  ‘Do the statement like this’
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `[]` from data.

```
data = file.getInput();
```

Comment: I would not downvote this answer if it had some kind of explanation as to why the OP needs to do this.